# Why is Visual C++ 2010 using this Assembly syntax for memory addressing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, visual-c++, addressing-mode

I converted the following C++ code into Assembly using Visual C++ 2010:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    i = 1234;

    return 0;
}
```

I received the following output:

[image]

Based on my understanding of memory addressing, the computation for the memory address is always placed inside of the square brackets, so why is the `_i$` in this case is placed outside of the square brackets?

Comment: Because the syntax allows it?

Comment: maybe because it related to stack frame? `i` is local, and a local variable address is related to the stack frame, what you see is relative address calculation. global variables addresses are fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's assembler treats something like `a[b]` about the same way C or C++ would so `a[b]` and `b[a]` are pretty much equivalent. Both indicate addition and some optional scaling followed by dereferencing, but don't place many requirements about which part is "address" and which part is "index".

Comment: The normal Intel assembler syntax is offset[register], or optionally [register+offset], but register[offset] is normally not allowed, since [] implies register indirection, and register without [] implies register direct access.